# Automatic scroll to element using Appium is not working in android

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I am trying to automate android application.in which I need to scroll down to one element and given scroll code are not working

Appium Scroll code is not working

I have tried this code

```
MobileElement l=driver.findElement( io.appium.java_client.MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"Link Patient to Doctor\");"));
l.click();
```

also tried this code

```
MobileElement li=driver.findElement(MobileBy.
 * AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new    UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"Link Patient to Doctor\").instance(0))"
 * ));li.click();
```

the page should scroll dowm to the Given text

my appium version is 2.0.0-beta.71
npm is 9.5.1

but its not scrolling down and showing the error:

> org.open
> qa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Could not parse selector
> expression `new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("Link Patient to Doctor")`: Unclosed paren in
> expression For documentation on this error, please visit:
> https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
> '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'DESKTOP-VQLLA2K', ip:
> '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
> '10.0', java.version: '19.0.1' Driver info:
> io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver Capabilities {app:
> D:\app-release.apk, appActivity: com.calculator_apps.MainAct...,
> appPackage: com.calculator_apps, automationName: UiAutomator2,
> databaseEnabled: false, desired: {app: D:\app-release.apk,
> appActivity: com.calculator_apps.MainAct..., appPackage:
> com.calculator_apps, automationName: UiAutomator2, deviceName:
> samsung, platformName: android, platformVersion: 10}, deviceApiLevel:
> 29, deviceManufacturer: samsung, deviceModel: SM-A305F, deviceName:
> RZ8M5181Y3M, deviceScreenDensity: 420, deviceScreenSize: 1080x2340,
> deviceUDID: RZ8M5181Y3M, javascriptEnabled: true,
> locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true,
> pixelRatio: 2.625, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android,
> platformVersion: 10, statBarHeight: 83, takesScreenshot: true,
> viewportRect: {height: 2048, left: 0, top: 83, width: 1080}, warnings:
> {}, webStorageEnabled: false} Session ID:
> 9641d029-12e2-4f87-bab0-86d49bcbeaa2
> *** Element info: {Using=-android uiautomator, value=new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollIntoView(new
> UiSelector().text("Link Patient to Doctor");}

please reply if anyone knows the solution

Comment: It's `InvalidSelectorException`. Check if `text(\"Link Patient to Doctor\")` identifies the element uniquely, possibly `text('Link Patient to Doctor')` would.

Comment: thank you but i tried other elements too..still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this there is issues in your code. try this.
driver.findElement(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("WebView"));")).click();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).